# Expo connection error | Could not load expo:// my-ip. Network response timed out

Tags: react-native, expo

My `react-native` app with the `expo-cli` wont run on my phone. Getting a network time-out error

Today I tried to start my `react-native` app with the `expo-cli` on my phone, but when trying to connect to the app using the `expo-cli` I got a network time out error.

Yesterday everything  was working fine and my app was able to run on my phone using the CLI.

I've also tried running my other `react-native` apps using `expo` and got the same error message. I rebooted my systeem, my phone and reinstalled the `expo` app on to my phone.

I've noticed that the expo app is not running on the same port as the `metro bundler` not sure if it's always been this way or if I just started noticing this.

[image: Different ports]

I've also tried to run the apps in the explore section of the `expo` app and those seem to work.

I start my app in the `cmd` on Windows with the command `expo start`, but since today started getting the error Could not load `expo:// my-ip. Network response time out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the connection type from `LAN` to `Funnel`